# Issue with embedding Video in Chrome by php in looping

Tags: php, google-chrome, video, youtube, embed

Hi i am using below 3 codes to embed videos in php.

```
echo ("object width=\"425\" height=\"350\" data=\"http:// youtube. com/v/".$vid. "\"". " type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\">");

echo ("param name=\"src".$i."\" value=\"http:// youtube. com/watch?v=". $vid."\"" ." /></object></p>");

echo "iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http:// youtube. com/embed/". $vid."\"". "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

echo "embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"425\" height=\"350\" src=\"http:// youtube . com/embed/".$vid." wmode=\"transparent\"></embed>";
```

But all i can see is white space when i use them in loop. When i use them independently, they work fine but when i use them in loop i can just a white space in place of video.

I have deliberately skipped < in above commands because stackoverflow was considering them tags

Please let me know in case you any information about it.

Thanks.
Jatin

Comment: I don't know why my tags are not coming..

Comment: do you have a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe different name using your loop.

```
for($x=0;$x<=n;$x++){
    echo "iframe width=\"420\" name="vid$x" height=\"315\" src=\"http:// youtube. com/embed/". $vid."\"". "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

}
```

Like that. It depends on how you name your control using the loop